# Boolean operations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm confused on how Python evaluates boolean statements.

For ex.

```
False and 2 or 3
```

returns 3

How is this evaluated? I thought Python first looks at 'False and 2', and returns False without even looking at 'or 3'. What is the order of what Python sees here?

Another is:

```
1 or False and 2 or 2 and 0 or 0
```

returns 1

From what I gathered from the first example, I thought Python would evaluate from left to right, so '1 or False' would return 1, then '1 and 2' would return 2, then '2 or 2' would return the first 2, then '2 and 0' would return 0, then '0 or 0' would return the second 0.

As you can tell I'm pretty perplexed here, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`and` has higher precedence than `or`.

```
False and 2 or 3
```

is evaluated as

```
((False and 2) or 3)
```

Since the first part `(False and 2)` is `False`, Python has to evaluated the second part to see whether the whole condition can still become `True` or not. It can, since `3` evaluates to `True` so this operand is returned.

Similar for `1 or False and 2 or 2 and 0 or 0` which is evaluated as

```
(1 or ((False and 2) or ((2 and 0) or 0)))
```

Since `1` evaluates to `True`, the whole condition will be `True`, no matter which value the other operands have. Python can stop evaluating at this point and again, returns the operand that determines the final value.

Stopping as early as the final result is determined is called [*short-circuit evaluation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and can be described as follows:

Whenever the final result of the expression is determined, the evaluation is stopped and in Python the value of the operand that determines the final value is returned. That is, assuming a left-to-right evaluation:

- for the `and` operator, the left-most operand that evaluates to `False` (or the last one)
- for the `or` operator, the left-most operand that evaluates to `True` (or the last one)

Comment: Ah so any comparison with and should be enclosed in their own parentheses. That makes a lot more sense. How did you know to do (1 or (((False and 2) or (2 and 0)) or 0)) instead of (1 or (False and 2) or (2 and 0) or 0)?

Comment: @kkSlider Only if you need to change the order of precedence, or want to make it clearer - just as in normal mathematics. Excessive bracketing will make your code less clear. As to your example. it's a matter of what the logic is for your situation.

Comment: @kkSlider: It does not have to be if you don't want to enforce a certain order. But it has to if you want to evaluate the expression as `False and (2 or 3)`. *edit:* what @Lattyware said :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that there is an order to evaluation, and [`and` has a higher precedence than `or`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary). As such, they are evaluated left-to-right here.

Given this, `False and 2 or 3` is, to python, `(False and 2) or 3` - so it evaluates to `False or True`, then to `True`.

In your next example, Python short-circuits, so `1 or False` evaluates to `True` as `1` does, and therefore returns `1`. The rest never gets evaluated. This makes sense as if the one part of an `or` is `True`, you know the whole thing must be - so why bother doing extra work?

A good way to check this is to define functions that print:

```
>>> def test(x):
...     print("Test: "+str(x))
...     return x
... 
>>> test(1) or test(0) or test(3)
Test: 1
1
>>> test(0) or test(0) or test(3)
Test: 0
Test: 0
Test: 3
3
>>> test(False) and test(2) or test(3)
Test: False
Test: 3
3
>>> test(1) or test(False) and test(2) or test(2) and test(0) or test(0)
Test: 1
1
```

This makes it easy to see what gets evaluated, and in what order.

Answer (score 3):

Check out section 5.15 of this page: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html

`or` has a lower precendence than `and`, so your statement is evaluated as

```
(false and 2) or 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I read about this a while back on the python docs page. If I find it, I'll post the reference.
It stated something along the lines of, in a boolean statement, Python will return the first True object. Hence....the and was pre-falsed with False, but the or only had one argument, which was 3 (True).

Comment: I had some bad typing here, but yes, as others have mentioned, the first step is the order of boolean precedence, and the next is that Python wouldn't return only a True or False for the statement, but the actual value (which could have a True or False).

Answer (score 2):

It is evaluated like that:

```
result = (False and 2) or 3
```

So basically if `False and 2` is true-ish, then it is returned, otherwise `3` is returned.